# Databaseless Rails Application Not Reloading Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I have a databaseless Rails 5.2.3 application (it's getting all data through an API). Whenever I make a change to the model I have to restart my server to get the changes to take effect. I have the following line in my development.rb file:

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

I'm using Webrick as my development database.

I'm pretty sure this is happening because I don't have a database in the application but I can't figure out how to get it to reload models without restarting Webrick.

Comment: What do you mean by reloading model?

Comment: From some of the research I've done, other threads say to make sure you do a rake migration to make sure all the models are loaded. I'm not doing any migrations because I don't have any database models (I do have models, just not connected to a database and no ActiveRecord).

Comment: And in case I misunderstood your question, Ali, I mean that whenever I make a change to a model, that change is not reflected unless I restart Webrick. It works fine when I make controller or view changes, just not model changes.